# Debian Buster Tor crash upon attempt to re-install it anew

Tags: debian

Well I have got this much upon attempt to run `./start-tor-browser -v` http://paste.debian.net/1115484/ and have no clue how to update Tor from its crushed state? On top of the run I got a graphic window with "Connect to Tor" message in its header and absolutely blank content. How to upgrade it from here?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be that issue that is reported here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/1798999

After you updated, your apparmor profile probably got screwed up. The suggested fix is to run:

```
sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.firefox
```

This specific command is for people having the issue with plain firefox. I don't run Debian so I can't tell you specifically what the same of the apparmor profile name is but you should be able to go to /etc/apparmor.d/ and find the one for Tor Browser.

Another option is to simply run Tor Browser directly and not with torbrowser-launcher.

Comment: Yes it has worked out with `sudo apparmor_parser -R /etc/apparmor.d/torbrowser.Browser.firefox` instead. Thanks a lot!